# Twitter OAUTH Acces Token Response in JSON

Tags: json, api, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm using Twitter's REST API to authorize an app. I just authorized the app with

> https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize

and got an oauth_verifier from the redirect uri.

Then I just used

> https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token

to get an access_token.

The problem is that the format of response I got from this method is `text/plain`. It's just like

> oauth_token=783897656863051776-5hQfcJTv4FzFpPcyVRbnjPUbJXR29&oauth_token_secret=MViTPOOCaHNZrW6HTIFZ340bq1rutJKL8oqkBxRp2aiW&user_id=783897656863051776&screen_name=sWest&x_auth_expires=0

My query is that how to get the response in `application/json format`.
Any help will be appreciated !!!

Comment: do you really want to share your token, secret and ids with all of us? :)

Comment: It's not original !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to parse it like application/x-www-form-urlencoded content, any language with HTTP Client libraries should provide this functionality.  But it isn't clear what language and libraries you are using.

This [example](https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial/services/twitter/TwitterAuthFlow.java#L68) uses joauth library to parse

```
  protected static Map<String, String> parseTokenMap(String tokenDetails) {
    KeyValueHandler.SingleKeyValueHandler handler =
        new KeyValueHandler.SingleKeyValueHandler();

    KeyValueParser.StandardKeyValueParser bodyParser =
        new KeyValueParser.StandardKeyValueParser("&", "=");
    bodyParser.parse(tokenDetails, Collections.singletonList(handler));

    return handler.toMap();
  }
```

Comment: What is your aim then? Understand the full set of commands done manually? Submit some request without a client?

Comment: Thank you :) Saved my time !